# How to create a Horizontally Infinite Sliding Image Gallery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a Image Gallery which keeps on sliding to left side of screen. Many images will be uploaded which has to automatically set in a horizontal masonry and this whole thing has to slide horizontally automatically.

This image would give an idea what exactly I want.

[image]

I searched a lot and but I didn't get anything near to it. That's why I even can't create a JSfiddle. Is it even possible?

Please Help

Comment: Have you a limited number of images, or will more and more be loaded into the component?

Comment: use [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=infinite+carousel), or try [this one](https://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/)

Comment: first thing first `scroll` and `slide` are 2 different terms so do you still plan to `scroll` items to left or you want the items to keep `sliding` to left ?

Comment: Or you could try to imagine a solution and actually code it. If you find any specific problem during the development, ask a question here and people will help you. That's how it works and how people actually learn to code.

Comment: @Paul As it is a gallery so more images could be added but if not possible we could limit the images by 30-40

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Keep them **sliding** to left

Comment: @giorgio Sorry but That is Carousel, what I want is a Horizontal Masonry Grid of images.

Comment: @JordiNebot Well I know that but I need a push to start things, Even I am not clear how to do it.

Comment: @codecraft, you can drop anything in the carousel you want, including a horizontal masonry grid of images. But whatever you'd want to do, show us what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

For a startup this might help you out, although you want several image thumbs lined up and sliding to left and current demo has single image, but you can treat every single image as a container and use the idea behind,  for understanding how it is happening with `CSS Only` there is a nice [article](https://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/) about it and a [codepen](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/EyxPPm) too. It uses `CSS` only to create a infinite sliding gallery. There are several other that use `javascript` along with `css` too the choice is yours, see here for demo.

```css
.tech-slideshow {
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.tech-slideshow>div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 2526px;
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/collage.jpg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.tech-slideshow .mover-1 {
  animation: moveSlideshow 12s linear infinite;
}

.tech-slideshow .mover-2 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  background-position: 0 -200px;
  animation: moveSlideshow 15s linear infinite;
}

.tech-slideshow:hover .mover-2 {
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes moveSlideshow {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-66.6666%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tech-slideshow">
  <div class="mover-1"></div>
  <div class="mover-2"></div>
</div>
```